# Schedule cron job to run between 2:30AM to 10:30PM

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I want to run a spring batch job between 2:30 AM to 10:30 PM in every 10 mins.

Please suggest the expression for it to be added in `@Scheduled` annotation of spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these expression:

```
10/30 02-21 * * *
10,20,30 22 * * *
```